# Printing like Perl in C++

Tags: c++, printf

Can I do something like the following Perl code in C++ ?
i.e Replicate `$string` `n` times ?

```
printf ("%s\n",$string x 4);
```

Comment: Put it in a `for` loop?

Comment: There are 20+ such printf in my code, each with different strings, each need to be replicated different times. Putting `for` loop for each makes the code ugly.

Comment: Ugly code in C++? Say it isn't so.

Comment: Larry Wall seems to have managed it quite nicely.... ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While C++ doesn't have an `operator x`, C++ is a flexible enough language that you can write a named operator `x` whose job it is to multiply strings:

```
#include <string>
namespace strop {
  struct x_op {} x;
  struct x_lhs { std::string s; };
  x_lhs operator*( std::string s, x_op ) {
    return {std::move(s)};
  }
  std::string operator*( x_lhs&& lhs, std::size_t rhs ) {
    std::string retval;
    for( std::size_t i = 0; i < rhs; ++i ) {
      retval += lhs.s;
    }
    return retval;
  }
}
```

use:

```
#include <iostream>
using strop::x;
int main () {
  std::string foo = "foo";
  std::cout << (foo *x* 5) << "\n"; // if you prefer std::cout
  printf("%s", (foo *x* 5).c_str()); // if you prefer printf
}
```

The above uses some trivial C++11 features, but not essentially.

C++03 version (it is less efficient):

```
#include <string>
namespace strop {
  struct x_op {} x;
  struct x_lhs { std::string s; x_lhs(std::string s_):s(s_) {} };
  x_lhs operator*( std::string s, x_op ) {
    return x_lhs(s);
  }
  std::string operator*( x_lhs lhs, std::size_t rhs ) {
    std::string retval;
    for( std::size_t i = 0; i < rhs; ++i ) {
      retval += lhs.s;
    }
    return retval;
  }
}
```

amusingly, this works with string literals:

```
  std::cout << "bar" *x* 3 << "\n";
```

because they are turned into `std::string`s implicitly.  If you are using `printf`, you still need to wrap it in `().c_str()`, or you are risking undefined behavior (even if you never mention `std::string`).

You could instead overload some other non-named operator, but overloading operators when you own *neither* type in the overload is pretty rude, and can lead to complications.

The above technique uses the placeholder types of `x_op` and `x_lhs` to ensure that the overloaded operator will only come into effect when we are interacting with our named operator.

The choice of `*` to wrap our named operator `x` is because the operation is multiplication-like.

Bonus: Insane version of `operator*`, which uses bit values of the rhs to reduce the amount of string wrangling:

```
  std::string operator*( x_lhs lhs, std::size_t rhs ) {
    std::string retval;
    auto done = [rhs]( std::size_t n ) {
      return !(i < (sizeof(rhs)*8) && !(rhs &~std::size_t((1<<i)-1)));
    };
    for( int i = 0; true; ++i) {
      if (!done(i+1)) {
        if (rhs & (1 << i))
          retval += lhs;
        lhs += lhs;
        continue;
      } else {
        // high bit must be set, or we'd be done before, unless rhs was 0:
        if (rhs != 0)
          retval += std::move(lhs);
        break;
      }
    }
    return retval;
  }
```

which has not been tested, but amuses me.

Comment: As long as you're wrapping it in `*`, why not just overload the `*` operator?

Comment: I overload string and my type, not string and `int`.  My overloads are part of the `x_op` api.  If you overload `std::string * int`, you are messing with the api of types you do not own.  As an example, look at what happens when `std::string` adds a similar overload: raw overload becomes ambiguous, while mine does not because I own one of the two types.

Comment: It would have been a lot easier to just write `std::cout << x(foo,4)`.

Comment: @msalters but that would be insufficiently perl like!  And besides, infix is usually easier to read than prefix.

Answer (score 1):

No, not directly.  You need to do it yourself:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
  printf ("%s", astring);
printf ("\n");
```

Comment: Regarding your `Rep` function: That constructor, to my best knowledge, does not exist.

Comment: Indeed, propably confused with `std::string(5, 'x')`

Answer (score 1):

*Preface*: overloading operators is a nuanced practice.  If you're not careful, it can lead to code which is difficult to read and maintain.  That said ...

You could try overloading `operator*()`, but in order to make that work you'll need to use string objects and not bare c-strings.  The reason is that C++ does not allow you overload operators which only reference built-in types.  The `std::string` class is not built in to the language.
For example, the following function will do what you intend with std::string objects.  Note that the return type is a const char* to be compatible with `printf()`.

```
const char* operator*(const std::string& input, size_t repeat)
{
    std::string output;
    for (size_t ii=0; ii<repeat; ++ii)
        output += input;
    return output.c_str();
}
```

With that function you can then use the syntax you prefer if the strings are stored in std::string objects:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::string input = argv[1];
    printf("%s\n", input*3);                  // works
    printf("%s\n", std::string(argv[1])*3);   // works
    //printf("%s\n", argv[1]*3);                // compile error
}
```

A more natural C++ way of doing it would be to use `<iostream>`, which does not require you to mix `char*` and `std::string` types in the overloaded operator.

```
std::string operator*(const std::string& input, size_t repeat)
{
    std::string output;
    for (size_t ii=0; ii<repeat; ++ii)
        output += input;
    return output;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::cout << std::string(argv[1])*3 << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As impressive as @Yakk's overloading is, why not just define a simple function?

```
std::string repeat(const std::string& s, int times) {
  std::string res;
  res.reserve(s.size() * times);
  for (int i = 0; i < times; ++i)
    res += s;
  return s;
}
```

Then you can do

```
std::cout << repeat("foo", 4) << std::endl;
```

Prints `foofoofoofoo`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a for loop:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)

    cout<<string;
```